# Testing an angular event emitted with $emit

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to use jasmine spies in order to test Angular events being emitted by `$emit`.

The test below:

```
describe('DashboardCtrl', function () {
    var scope, httpBackend, domainService;
    beforeEach(module('bignibou', 'dashboard', 'utils'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _domainService_, messageService, $httpBackend) {
        domainService = _domainService_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            domainService: domainService,
            messageService: messageService,
            currentUserAccount: {data: {firstName: 'John'}},
            unreadMessagesCount: 0,
            latestMessages: []
        });
        spyOn(scope, '$emit');
        spyOn(scope, '$on');
        spyOn(domainService, 'currentUserAccount').and.returnValue(function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({id: 42, firstName: 'Pedro'});
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/current-useraccount').respond({id: 42, firstName: 'Pedro'});
    }));
    it('should handle user account updated', function () {
        scope.$emit('useraccount:updated');
        expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(domainService.currentUserAccount).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.currentUserAccount.firstName).toEqual('Pedro');
    });
});
```

yields:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) DashboardCtrl should handle user account updated FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'spyOn(domainService, 'currentUserAccount').and.returnValue')
            at /Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-site/bignibou-client/test/unit/dashboard.spec.js:17
            at invoke (/Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-site/bignibou-client/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473)
            at workFn (/Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-site/bignibou-client/src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2426)
        undefined
        Expected spy $on to have been called.
        Expected spy currentUserAccount to have been called.
        Expected 'John' to equal 'Pedro'.
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.005 secs / 0.034 secs)
```

From my domainService:

```
currentUserAccount: function () {
    return $http.get('/api/utils/current-useraccount', {
        cache: false
    });
},
```

From DashboardCtrl:

```
$scope.$on('useraccount:updated', function () {
    domainService.currentUserAccount().success(function (data) {
        $scope.currentUserAccount = data;
    });
});
```

I am not sure what I am getting wrong. Can anyone please tell me why the `$on` listener function is not invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my test did not need any jasmine spy actually.

I just want to ensure that the correct value is set on the `$scope` as follows:

```
describe('DashboardCtrl', function () {
    var scope, httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('bignibou', 'dashboard', 'utils'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, domainService, messageService, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            domainService: domainService,
            messageService: messageService,
            currentUserAccount: {data: {firstName: 'John'}},
            unreadMessagesCount: 0,
            latestMessages: []
        });

        httpBackend = $httpBackend;

        //TODO: do I need all those expectations?
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/signup-roles').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/parents-needs').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/childcare-worker-types').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/childcare-types').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/all-day-to-time-slots').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/regular-day-to-time-slots').respond({});
        httpBackend.whenGET('/info').respond({build: {version: '1.0'}});
        httpBackend.whenGET(/app.+/).respond({});

        httpBackend.whenGET('/api/utils/current-useraccount').respond({id: 42, firstName: 'Pedro'});
    }));
    it('should handle user account updated', function () {
        scope.$emit('useraccount:updated');
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(scope.currentUserAccount.firstName).toEqual('Pedro');
    });
});
```

Notice that I now call `flush()`.

The test above works but is not very clean because I need to provide all the outstanding expectations to the httpBackend...

I guess that's another issue.

Comment: Doing the the things like that is the domain of integration/e2e tests. For unit tests you'd better stick to mocking controller dependencies. Mocking `domainService.currentUserAccount` with resolved promise and then expecting `currentUserAccount` on scope is the right thing to to here. 'expect` on the listener isn't really necessary but is a valid addition here.

Answer (score 1):

You need `spyOn(scope, '$on')` before `$controller` is being called, because `$on` is called in controller constructor function. But since you want to spy on the listener, you can do this instead:

```
  $controller('DashboardCtrl', ...);
  listeners = scope.$$listeners['useraccount:updated'];
  spyOn(listeners, 0);
```

And in `it`:

```
  scope.$emit('useraccount:updated');
  expect(listeners[0]).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the $scope.$on function takes 2 arguments:

- the event you are trying to subscribe to
- the function that you would like to execute when the event is triggered

This means that $scope.$on gets called when the Controller gets initialised, not when the event gets emitted.

So if you want to check that your function gets called, you can do the following:

1. Add your function to $scope (or to a variable)

   $scope.update = function () {
       domainService.currentUserAccount().success(function (data) {
           $scope.currentUserAccount = data;
       });
   }
2. List item

   $scope.$on('useraccount:updated', $scope.update);
3. Amend your test:

   spyOn($scope, 'update');
   expect(scope.update).toHaveBeenCalled();

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Hi! Do I really need to change my application design and introduce a function within the scope i.e. update?

Comment: ok not necessarily I guess. In your case specifically you are only performing 1 action when the event is triggered, so I guess spying on domainService to be called is good enough.

Comment: However what you should understand is that $scope.$on does not get called every time the event gets emitted, but only gets called once. And during that call the function passed as second argument gets registered for a specific event.